# .NET Configuration File Cache

Tags: .net, configuration

I thought that .NET updates its cache every time the source configuration file gets updated without having to restart the application domain.

I realize it doesn't. Or am I missing something?

Comment: As I guess from the comments your question is about web.config. Is restarting your web application not a suitable option for you? I'd be surprised if there was a way around that because web.config also contains IIS configuration settings.

Comment: I wasn't talking just about web.config. Whenever there's a change to web.config, ASP.NET automatically restarts the IIS process and refreshes the configuration cache. The problem is with non-Web based applications and their app.config files.

Answer (score 1):

There is no cache for configuration files.

You can refresh your loaded configuration, but it takes a little effort. I assume you could set a FileSystem event on the `app.config` to get notified.

See some older questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502411/change-connection-string-reload-app-config-at-run-time) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024072/how-to-reload-an-assembly-in-c-for-a-net-application-domain).

Comment: There *is*. That is why the configuration values read into the System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings classes don't change when you change the source configuration file.

Also, if you read Fritz Onion's Essential ASP.NET, he discusses it in detail in the chapter devoted to configuration files.

Comment: ASP.NET does things a little different. If you mean web.config, edit the tags.

Comment: I think I have the answer to my question. I guess Microsoft realized it halfway through and that is why they created the new System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager class and made the ConfigurationSettings class obsolete.

I am just going to try my same example using the ConfigurationManager class instead of the ConfigurationSettings class.

Comment: Nope, the ConfigurationManager class doesn't refresh the cache either.

Comment: Hi Henk, it is *especially* with web.config that ASP.NET caches the configuration. However, ASP.NET also refreshes the cache everytime the file is updated and restarts the IIS process.

Comment: Thank you, Henk. I am aware of the RefreshSection method. But that requires me to take care of manual refresh. I was thinking of a way that .NET did it itself. Apparently, there isn't, so I'll have to write my own.