# How can I force the application to use only library from the specified path in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have some simple console application written in C# (using VS2008).

In this application I want to check the current version of some library. I have the path to the library, but when I replace the library with some other (I move first library to other directory) somehow my application is still 'looking' at the first library instead of 'looking' at the library in given path.

The code looks like this:

```
private void Sth()
{
   Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(libPath);
   Version ver = assembly.GetName().Version;
}
```

And I call this method every period of time (so the assembly should load the file properly).

So when I starts my app and the version of library in given path is 1.0.0.0 my app shows it correctly. But when I replace the library file with new one (with version 2.0.0.0) my application still shows 1.0.0.0. But when I close my application and run it again It will show 2.0.0.0 correctly.

Why is that happening?

Best wishes, Pete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your comments to evanmcdonnal's answer, what you need is to determine the version of the assembly without loading it. You can (I even think you should) use [AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.getassemblyname.aspx) which does exactly what you need: retrieve the Name of the assembly, not loading it.

I have quickly tested the approach and it succeded to show correct output after I have replaced the dll file.

```
var initialName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("Foo.dll");
Console.WriteLine(initialName);
Console.WriteLine(initialName.Version);
// replaced the dll manually

initialName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("Foo.dll");
Console.WriteLine(initialName);
Console.WriteLine(initialName.Version);
```

Hope it helps,
Ivan.

Answer (score 3):

The assembly is only loaded once. swapping the dll's during execution won't change the version which is loaded. It's not like the application is going to that path each time some line of code from that assembly executes. The whole thing is loaded into memory and then the path (and what happens to be there) is no longer relavent. After you close the app and start it again it goes to the folder and loads whichever assembly you have there so you get v2.

From what I understand there is no way to change assemblies mid execution. This [How to reload an assembly for a .NET Application Domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024072/how-to-reload-an-assembly-for-a-net-application-domain) question discusses it and the top answer says you can't unload an assembly.

EDIT:

```
 var assemblyInfo = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(pathToMyAssembly); //get assembly
 Version assemblyVersion = assemblyInfo.Version; // get version
 Version minVersion = new Version(1, 1, 4); // minimum version of 1.1.4
 if (minVersion.CompareTo(assemblyVersion) < 0)
       // the version is less than the minimum.
       // do something to reconcile problem
```

Comment: Right, you cannot just reload an assembly within an AppDomain, However, you can load the assembly in an AppDomain and unload the entire AppDomain.

Comment: +1. Note that if your application depends on ability to load particular version of assembly from place you like you need to read about assembly loading context, publisher policy redirects... I.e. you'll find that GACed assembly will be always preferred to local one... i.e. [Suzanne Cook's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2004/08/04/load-assemblyname.aspx) articles are very useful for that.

Comment: Maybe I have not mentioned that, but I am not checking the .dll that my application uses. What I want to do is to check the version of library of already running service, and if it's too old I want to do something. So it's not that I loaded the .dll to run my application. I want to treat this .dll like normal file, it could be event .txt. All I want to do is to check the version of file, which is located on this path. Can I do it otherwise?

Comment: @PeteMorrison I've edited with some sample code on how to get and compare assembly versions.