# Assembly.LoadFrom load wrong assembly

Tags: c#, memory-management, dll, resources

I'm using Assembly.LoadFrom to load my dll and create an instance of it later.

Here is my problem. 
Sometime I can modify my dll. More precisely I delete it and create a new one with the same name and path. And when I instantiate it again and call methods I see that the instance being used is the first one.

If I close my application and call my method the good instance is being used.

So is there a way to deallocate resources or free the instance ? Here is my sample code

```
Assembly sampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(pathToDll);
MyClassEntity = sampleAssembly.CreateInstance("InstanceName") as MyClass;
```

MyClass is an abstract class.

Answer (score 3):

Assemblies are loaded once and kept in memory.  You'd have to load it into a separate `AppDomain` and rid the domain to rid the loaded assembly.

See this link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173101.aspx

And this:  [How to reload an assembly for a .NET Application Domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024072/how-to-reload-an-assembly-for-a-net-application-domain)